# Queue owned cases report, show only member queue cases

Tags: reporting, case, service-cloud-console, dashboard, queue

How can I create a report which only shows cases owned by queues in which the current user is member.

eg: 
Case1, owner: queue1
Case2, owner: queue2

User1 is member of queue1 and queue2, User2 is only member of queue1.

When running the same dashboard(the report will be in a dashboard), the User1 should see both cases & User2 should only see Case1.

Answer (score 2):

OWD of the case must be defined as `Private`.

Create a case report and choose `Queue owned cases` from the dropdown.

[image: Queue owned cases]