# View report records by queues not working

Tags: reporting, security, custom-report-type, custom-reports, owd

I have a custom report (Sales Orders with Work orders) but it doesn't filter out by queues.

Both objects are on PRIVATE in the OWD and I have set the filter to the one in the print screen

Any user can see any sales order from any queue when logged in

What can I do to resolve this issue?
I have followed this help link but it still doensn't work:
[help link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218768/queue-owned-cases-report-show-only-member-queue-cases)

[image]

Comment: It seems like both Sales Order and Work Order are custom objects? Or perhaps from a package? Does Sales Order have any Master-Detail fields? Have you confirmed that the affected users don't have View All for the Sales Order object in profile or permission set, or the View All Data system permission?

Comment: Looking at your screen, the report should show all Sales Orders with Work Orders that are owned by ANY Queue. Does what you're seeing in the report also include Sales Orders that are owned by Users?

Comment: Also, when you say "Any user can see any sales order from any queue when logged in," is this expected behavior because of sharing rules?